# En quoi « de part ni d’autre » veut-il dire « to either party » ?

Tags: étymologie, négation

J'ai rencontré ce syntagme prépositionnel [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bout#.C3.89tymologie):

> Bout à bout avait le sens de « coup pour coup, sans avantage **de part ni d’autre** ».

[Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/de-part-ni-dautre.3047281/#post-15400859)  indique :

> it's legalese for "either party".

Comment  ces 5 mots se sont-ils combinés pour vouloir dire « to either party » ? Comment décomposer la syntaxe, mot à mot ?

Étant donné que le jargon juridique est suranné, je soupçonne qu'il en va de même pour la syntaxe.

Si j'ai raison, qu'est-ce que  [ni](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ni#.C3.89tymologie) signifie ici?

Son étymon latin, [nec](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nec#la), exprime la négation, mais je ne vois aucune négation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La formule est une abréviation par sous-entendu :

> [ni] d'une part ni d'[une] autre [part].

En arrêtant la phrase à *autre*, il ne peut y avoir que le mot *part* pour compléter.

Voici le sens de « de part ni d’autre »: qu'on ne trouve *nulle part* (dans aucune des parts), on peut trancher le problème en autant de part que l'on veut, il n'y a pas de solution possible.

Il s'agit d'un effet qui vient contrer la balance oratoire :

> ..(exposé des arguments).. *d'une part*, ..(exposé des arguments contraires).. *d'autre part*.
>
> ..(exposé des arguments).. que l'on ne trouve nulle part (ni d'un coté, ni de l'autre).

Le code français oblige à la contraction de texte, aucun mot ne peut être enlevé d'une loi sans en déformer le sens, sans rendre le texte incompréhensible ou incorrect.

Toute morceau de phrase qui peut être réécrit avec moins de mots sera réécrit, ainsi on évite les sens ambigus, les interprétations non souhaitées, selon que l'on s'appuie sur la nuance d'un mot qui est redéfinit plus ou moins précisément par un autre mot que l'on peut supprimer.

Cela lui donne un aspect suranné et conservateur, mais la Loi ne peut pas être interprétée d'une autre façon. Les avocats en font leur beurre.
Cependant le langage administratif français est en cours de ré-écriture, il met au goût du jour son vocabulaire et ses formulations, afin que tout un chacun puisse comprendre les textes.